# how to write a method to create sqlite table in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to write a class in order to create an sqlite table since I have to create quite a few tables for this assignment.

This is how I tried to approach:

```
def connect_database(database_name):
    table_connect = lite.connect(database_name)
    print "connected successfully"
    return table_connect


def create_table(name_of_table, *argument_name, *argument_type):

    # create_user = user_table.cursor()
    # create_user.execute("Drop table if EXISTS  user_table")
    # create_user.execute('create table user_table(user_id INT, user_name VARCHAR )')
    # create_user.close()

    table_create = name_of_table.cursor()
    table_create.execute("drop table if exists name_of_table")
    table_create.execute('''
    create table name_of_table(
      argument_name  argument_type
      argument_name  name_of_table
    )
    ''')

    print "create table successfully"

    table_create.close()

example = connect_database('example.db')
create_table(example, water, FLOAT)
```

The problems I have is not being able to pass multiple argument_names, or pass argument_type in the method.

Also, the program returns unresolved reference for water and FLOAT.

Is there anyway that I can finish the method?

Thanks

Comment: Tip: to properly format code [edit] your question and use the `{}` button after selecting it

Comment: And your unresolved reference error doesn't mean anything with the code you've shown. You can read about making a [mcve] for more information

Comment: you want to write a method that executes SQL commands? you're going to pass multiple arguments to the method but you can't? what are you going to do?

Answer (score 1):

really you should probably consider using an ORM like sqlalchemy ... writing your own database abstraction, based on the your current skill level is probably a recipe for disaster, however if you really must try something like this

```
def create_table_string(table_name,*fields):
    return "CREATE TABLE {table_name} ({fields})".format(table_name=table_name,
                                                         fields=",".join(fields))

def create_table(cursor,name_of_table, *fields):
    sql = create_table_string(table_name,*fields)
    print "SQL:",sql
    cursor.executescript(sql)

db = sqlite3.connect(my_database)
create_table(db.cursor(),"a_table","Field1 INT","Field2 String","Field3 PRIMARY KEY INTEGER")
```